# XPath. Extract value of attribute from other attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

Could you please clarify is it possible to extract the value of an attribute by requesting other attribute via XPath?

For Example:

```
<Attributes>
 <Attribute>
   <Id>5</Id>
   <Value>56757364</Value>
 </Attribute>
</Attributes>

<Attributes>
 <Attribute>
   <Id>6</Id>
   <Value>23372670</Value>
 </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

I have to get `'23372670'` by requesting `Id = 6`.

And I can't use

```
//Attributes/Attribute[1]/Value
```

because my XML files contains many Attributes with different order of attributes.

Comment: These are elements, not attributes, despite being named 'Attribute'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
/Attributes/Attribute[Id=6]/Value
```

or if you need to preserve `Attribute` node structure

```
/Attributes/Attribute/Id[.=6]/following-sibling::Value
```

Comment: One more question please. If I have two or more Attributes I should use their number:

`/Attributes/Attribute[2]/Id[.=6]/following-sibling::Value`

Is there any way to avoid it? I have to use just Id.

Comment: @ruhagen , if Id value (`6`) is unique, you don't need to specify index: `/Attributes/Attribute/Id[.=6]/following-sibling::Value` still should be enough

Comment: Thanks. I will test it